# Préposition et pronom

Tags: grammaire, sens

- Première question :

  > Dès avant la guerre, il s'était installé dans cette ville.

Que signifie *dès* dans cette phrase ?

- Deuxième question:

  > Que Rousseau triomphe, sa gloire d'un moment n'en sera que plus détestée.

Que signifie *en* dans cette phrase ?

Comment: Conseil: il est recommandé de faire 2 questions séparées dans un cas comme celui-ci, où les deux questions ne sont pas liées.

Answer (score 4):

*Dès* est une préposition qui signifie *aussitôt, à partir de* (cf [ici](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A8s)). Il peut être surprenant de voir deux prépositions utilisées l'une après l'autre dans *dès avant la guerre*, mais c'est néanmoins correct. Il faut comprendre, si l'on paraphrase très explicitement mot à mot: "aussitôt à partir de la période avant la guerre".

Dans *Que Rousseau triomphe, sa gloire d'un moment n'en sera que plus détestée*, le pronom *en* exprime la cause et remplace *que Rousseau triomphe* (notez que le *que* introduit ici une proposition conditionnelle). En paraphrasant, on pourrait dire *Si Rousseau triomphe, sa gloire d'un moment ne sera que plus détestée à cause de cela*.

Comment: *Aussitôt à partir de la période avant..* n'est pas très heureux, je dirais plutôt simplement: *déjà, avant la guerre...*

Comment: Oui, c'était une paraphrase très explicite pour tenter d'expliquer plus clairement le sens - je suis conscient que c'est boiteux.

Answer (score 0):

" dès avant" could be translated as " already before"

" en " is a pronoun used to stand for " of something" , for example " j'en veux" means " I want of this thing" . In your example, " en " means " of this fact" , " de ce fait" ( with a causal meaning".